# A text editor which allows texts to be filed under keywords?

Tags: text-editor

I need a program which takes some text (usually just a few lines) and files it under some keywords. Then, later on, I can search for all texts that have been filed under certain keywords.

For example, I may file the text "Dog" under the keyword "Animal", and I may file the text "Cat" under the keywords "Animal" and "Cute", and then later on, if I search for texts with the keyword "Animal" + "Cute", it should return the "Cat"-text, and nothing else (unless of course there are other texts with both these keywords  saven with it).

Is there such a text editor? Can I somehow do it "manually" with Word or what have you (in an easy way, of course)?

Comment: So you have blocks of text which are usually a few lines so perhaps less than 100 words. You want to be able to store these blocks of text in a kind of database or storage as a complete unit and attach one or more keywords or tags that describe the block of text? And you want to be able to search on the tags using a kind of language that allows you to combine several of the tags in a search criteria. So you want to ask questions like "find all blocks of text with tags of animal and cute" and be given a list of those text blocks?

Answer (score 1):

**Boostnote** can do it. It is free app for main OSes. But it's slow.

After created a note, click "Add tag" and type a tag.
Later on, you can do search for "#tagname" - it shows notes with such tag.